# How do I use the start_mining command?

Tags: monerod

I'm new, and I need help.
I started a Monero node, and as soon as it was synchronized, it closed the node. I don't know why. Can somebody tell me the reason?
Also I want to know how to insert the right command for start_mining. It is telling me that is the wrong command.

Comment: Can you use this command on the p2pool server? The command is there no address does it pay out to the address that starts p2pool?

Answer (score 1):

monerod, the Monero node, should not exit once it's synchronized. Maybe a bug caused it to crash. If this is so, please include any error messages or logs or console output.

As for the `start_mining` command, it takes a first parameter for the Monero address you want to mine with (the address to which any block reward will be paid to), and an optional number of threads to use (you want to ensure each thread has at least 2MB of cache memory to use).

For example:

`start_mining 4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 2`

This will start 2 mining threads, paying to 4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.

Note that this is solo mining, and the time between getting blocks can be pretty large if your hash rate isn't so good. If you have low hash rate, consider pool mining, unless the high variance doesn't bother you. In the long run, the payout is about the same.